# jquery ajax.abort(), how to resend again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drupal-7, xmlhttprequest

This is in a Drupal context but i believe its common for all ajax requests.

On a beforeSend callback im aborting the request depending on DOM conditions like:

```
Drupal.ajax.prototype.beforeSend = function (xmlhttprequest, options) {
   if ($(this.element).hasClass('disabled')) {
     xmlhttprequest.abort();
   }
})
```

Why can't I reprocess this request afterwards?

I mean, when the link is clicked again the code doesn't even go through beforeSend()..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xmlhttprequest.open('GET', 'page.txt');
xmlhttprequest.send();
```

doing this will reinvoke interrupted request

Comment: when i click again the response is not even processed, won't even go through beforeSend